# Why is necessary use alias at calling object methods?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE TYPE person_typ AS OBJECT (
  idno           NUMBER,
  first_name     VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name      VARCHAR2(25),
  email          VARCHAR2(25),
  phone          VARCHAR2(20),
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER
);


CREATE TYPE BODY person_typ AS
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN idno;
  END;
END;




CREATE TABLE contacts (
  contact         person_typ,
  contact_date    DATE );

INSERT INTO contacts 
VALUES 
(  person_typ (65, 'Verna', 'Mills', 'vmills@example.com', '1-650-555-0125'), '24 Jun 2003' );
```

Then,  according to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjint.htm#CIHCBDHG)
when  need  call method  `get_idno()`, should be make this:

`SELECT c.contact.get_idno() FROM contacts c;`

Why is necessary here using alias? that is, why not works this:

`SELECT contacts.contact.get_idno() FROM contacts;`

?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare it to like object oriented programming.

```
You need to create the instance of an object , before using any methods of it .

You can not directly call it by using  contacts
```